# caffe: Test needed?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a really sophisticated net which takes up a lot of memory on my gpu. I have found out that if I train and test my data (which is the standard case) the memory usage is as twice as high as if I do only training. Is it really necessary to test my data? Or is it just used for visualisation, i.e. to show me if my net is overfitting or sth like that?

I assume it is necessary, but I do not know the reason. My question is: How to separate training and testing? I know you can do

```
test_initialization: false
```

But if I want to test my net how would I do that afterwards?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still have TEST phases in your layers?

Comment: No, should I? @Cassie

Comment: If you do, then you can use command line testing. If not, you can write a script. I am writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a TEST phase in your train.prototxt, you can use a command line to test your network. You can see this [link](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html), where they mention the following command line:

```
    # score the learned LeNet model on the validation set as defined in the
    # model architeture lenet_train_test.prototxt
    caffe test -model examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt -weights 
    examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel -gpu 0 -iterations 100
```

You can edit it to test your network.

There is also a [Python tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html) you can follow to load the trained network with a script and use it in the field. This can be manipulated to perform separate forward passes and compare the results with what you expect. I don't expect this to work completely out of the box, so you will have to try some things out.

Comment: Yeah but is this the same as if I would have a test phase whilst my training? Cause if that is so, why would I even need a test phase at all? @Cassie

Comment: Running TEST phases during training gives information on how well your model generalizes during training. This is of course not required, but it does gain insight on how quickly your model learns and if and when it overfits.

Comment: Ah ok, so it is in general just a "test" as it says but does not improve the training itself. Thank you!

Comment: From http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html I read that the TEST phase is indeed only reported and not used in backpropagation.